# "heroku run NNN" when there're several "remote" git repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have almost identical web apps on Heroku. It's a single folder, it's just that there're 2 remote repos at heroku: "prod" and "staging"

```
$ git remote -v

staging  https://git.heroku.com/my_app-staging.git (fetch)
staging  https://git.heroku.com/my_app-staging.git (push)
prod       https://git.heroku.com/my_app-prod.git (fetch)
prod       https://git.heroku.com/my_app-prod.git (push)
```

When running a command via heroku such "heroku run rails c", how can I specify which app - staging or prod - it should run on?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you got this sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
heroku run rails c --remote prod
```

or

```
heroku run rails c --remote staging
```